# AB testing: Only getting "Item has a test in draft message" in Sitecore 8.1

Tags: content-testing

AB Testing: In Test Definition Item under the Test Lab I have set the workflow as sample Workflow and workflow state as Awaiting Approval. But when I saved the item  I am only getting "item has a test in draft" notification message. There is no submit option visible in experience editor's notification area. How can I get "Create a test" option?

Comment: I also have the problem of not appearing "Create a test" option and only appears "item has a test in draft" notification. Already changed to use this <setting name="ContentTesting.AlwaysShowTestCandidateNotification" value="true" /> Any help?

Answer (score 2):

In Sitecore 8.1 and above there is a setting which can be turned on to allow the content authors to start test via experience editor.

Please add the below settings either as  patch config file or 
You can edit the value in the config file (Sitecore.ContentTesting.config).

Setting name is “ContentTesting.AlwaysShowTestCandidateNotification”

Answer (score 2):

If you have set the Sitecore setting `ContentTesting.AlwaysShowTestCandidateNotification` to `true` but you still do not see the "Create a test" link, it may be because that link will only display if the current item **does not have workflow**.  If you have workflow on the item, then you will need to use the workflow approach to content testing (which means you may need to create some custom workflow steps).

[Sitecore's documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/analyzing_and_reporting/experience_optimization__content_testing/setting_up_tests/adding_content_testing_to_a_workflow) for setting up a testing workflow step.